# Sending String using PrintWriter from Android comes to server in groups with big delay

Tags: java, android, sockets

In application I'm currently working on the client which is Android phone sends Strings to server at PC. Few first messages comes immediately but later messages stop incoming for some time and when they finally get to server they show up in a group. The connection work fine, both devices are connected to the same router so the problem is time between sending and receiving a message. Can this be caused by use of PrintWriter and Scanner?

```
try{
            s = new Socket(ip, PORT);
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()), true);
            isConnected = true;
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected successfully.");
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
```

And sending method:

```
void send(String msg){
    try{
        out.print(msg + "\n");
        out.flush();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: Have you tried using the `PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)` constructor to make sure everything is flushed immediately?

Comment: Yes, I set autoFlush to true. I will post my code in a minute.